# Can we ban the "writing" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We had a tag called "writing", which contained 16 or so questions about [orthography](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), [handwriting](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting), [composition](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition) and [name](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name) and other tags in a good mix. I don't think a word as general as writing should be made a synonym of any of these tags, so I went through the questions and retagged these questions accordingly. (The non-obvious choices I made were for off-topic questions.) Can we now ban its use?